# Is gas price paid by the transaction sender to the miner, or the miner reward is newly generated?

Tags: reward

A sender of transaction can specify the gas price it is willing to pay for the transaction.

Also, if there are no transactions, miners mine empty blocks and still get rewarded with newly generated ether.

So, if a miner mines a new block with a transaction submitted by some sender, what does the miner get as the reward? Is it newly generated ether, or ether from the senders account?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both. The miner always gets the block reward, in the form of newly-printed money if they mine a block. Then for each transaction that block includes, they also get to debit fees (user-defined gas price * gas used) from the account that sent the transaction.