# How much Ethereum is used daily in gas?

Tags: gas

I can see from this site - https://etherscan.io/chart/gasused - the amount of gas used on the Ethereum network daily.

What I cannot work out is how much ETH that corresponds to. Is there some other site that links gas-ether? Or is there a peg of gas->ether?

I mean, if i take avg Gwei as 2.5 - https://ethgasstation.info/

Do i just do

Eth = 2.5 * 10-9 * 35,819,000,000 = ~90 ETH

But then https://etherscan.io/chart/transactionfee has the transaction fee at 308 ETH. What am i missing?

Also, is that ETH "burnt" or lost, or does it get recycled back into use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eth Gas Station lists 2.5 GWei as their "Standard" gas price, which doesn't necessarily mean that it's the actual average gas price in the past day/week. I found this website that lists some useful statistics https://bitinfocharts.com/ethereum/.

The website states that the number of transactions in the last 24 hours was 553,359. It also states that the average transaction fee during this time was 0.00061 ETH. We can multiply these numbers to get ~337 ETH. This is similar to etherscan's figure of 308 ETH.

The transaction costs are given to the miners together with some newly created ETH. More information on this can be found in this question: [Is gas price paid by the transaction sender to the miner, or the miner reward is newly generated?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9742/is-gas-price-paid-by-the-transaction-sender-to-the-miner-or-the-miner-reward-is).

Answer (score 1):

The average gasPrice that you are using is too low, look at the [gasprice chart of etherscan](https://etherscan.io/chart/gasprice) the average is between 10 and 15 Gwei, using 12Gwei you get about 430 ether, which is closer to what you expected.

Hope this helps